# Typescript 'never' being inferred from generic return type

Tags: typescript

I have the following function

```js
export default function convertFilterToPrimitiveType<TFilterKey extends keyof Filters>(
  filterKey: TFilterKey,
  filterValue: FilterOption | [FilterOption]
): Filters[TFilterKey] {
// body
}
```

With the following type

```
type Filters = {
   sortBy: string;
   someOther: number[]
   bool: boolean;
}
```

The desired type checking is as follows:

- Users can only input a key `filterKey` from the type Filters
- The return type should match the return type of the chosen keys value type from the Filters object. e.g

```js
convertFilterToPrimitiveType('sortBy', {...}) // string
convertFilterToPrimitiveType('someOther', {...}) // number[]
convertFilterToPrimitiveType('bool', {...}) // bool
```

Quite simple.

But i am encountering an error when attempting to return anything.

Here is a simple example

```js
if (filterKey === 'sortBy') return 'test'
```

And I receive the following error

```
Type '"test"' is not assignable to type 'Filters[TFilterKey]'.
Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'
```

I don't understand how the `never` type is being inferred from the return type here.

If someone could explain to me why this is the case - and potentially suggest a fix , I would be very grateful!